# Return promise from a http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request, q

Making a precheck to see if images in an api actually exists. I'm using 'q' as my promise library and 'request' lib to make the http request. I'm trying to return an array of all the successfully requested images as so:

```
.then((data)=> {
  return q.all(data.map((elem) => {
    let deferred = q.defer()
    request(`https://address/path/${elem}.jpg`, (error, response) => {
      if (!error, response.statusCode === 200) {
        deferred.resolve(elem)
      }
    })
    return deferred.promise
  })
  )
})
.then((result)=> {
   console.log('Array of existing images', result)//Result should contain all image id's which had status code 200
})
```

I would expect this to return all results which had a request status of 200. With `q.all()` I expect the function to return once all promises are fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you shuld add one chain, where you clean non 200 images
for exemple, lik that

```
.then((data)=> {
    return q.all(data.map((elem) => {
            let deferred = q.defer()
            request(`https://address/path/${elem}.jpg`, (error, response) => {
                if (!error) {
                    deferred.resolve({img:elem, status : response.statusCode})
                }else{
                    deferred.reject({elem: 'error'})
                }
            });
            return deferred.promise
        })
    )
})
.then((result)=> {
        let onlyGoodImages = [];
        result.map((elem) => {
            if (elem.status == 200){
                onlyGoodImages.push(elem.img);
            }
        });
        return onlyGoodImages;
    }
)
.then((result)=> {
    console.log('Array of existing images', result)//Result should contain all image id's which had status code 200
})
```